# passing the selected checkbox values to the Database in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl

I'm using Struts2 and This is my form in JSP

```
<s:form target="_top" cssClass="table-controls form-wrapper" name="incentives" id="frmIncentives" action="saveIncentives.action" method="post">
        <div id="actionErrors" style="color: red;">
                        <s:actionerror />
                        <s:fielderror />
        </div>
            <table id ="showIncentives" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="500" >
                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                    <td><s:checkbox name="Select All" id="select_all"
                            theme="simple" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Marketing Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Advertising Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Channel Placement Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>
            <s:iterator value="incentiveList" status="stat">
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="pricingTierId" /> <s:hidden value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}" /></td>
                        <td><s:property value="marketingAmount" /> <s:hidden value="%{incentiveList.marketingAmount}" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="marketingIncentive" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="advertizingIncentive" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="channelPlacementIncentive" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
            </s:iterator>
            </table>
            <c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) == 0}">
                <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) gt 0}">
                <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="false"/>
            </c:if>
    </s:form>
```

And now method in my Action class is as below

```
private String marketingIncentive;
    private String advertizingIncentive;
    private String channelPlacementIncentive;
    private BigDecimal marketingAmount;
    private Integer pricingTierId;


    //getters and setters
    public String getMarketingIncentive() {
        return marketingIncentive;
    }
    public void setMarketingIncentive(String marketingIncentive) {
        this.marketingIncentive = marketingIncentive;
    }
    public String getAdvertizingIncentive() {
        return advertizingIncentive;
    }
    public void setAdvertizingIncentive(String advertizingIncentive) {
        this.advertizingIncentive = advertizingIncentive;
    }
    public String getChannelPlacementIncentive() {
        return channelPlacementIncentive;
    }
    public void setChannelPlacementIncentive(String channelPlacementIncentive) {
        this.channelPlacementIncentive = channelPlacementIncentive;
    }
    public BigDecimal getMarketingAmount() {
        return marketingAmount;
    }
    public void setMarketingAmount(BigDecimal marketingAmount) {
        this.marketingAmount = marketingAmount;
    }


    // Method to save the selected checkbox values 

    public String saveIncentives(){
        WorkFlowDAO workFlowDAO = new WorkFlowDAO();

        try {
            if(submit != null){

                IncentiveDetailsDO incentiveDetailsDO = new IncentiveDetailsDO();
                incentiveDetailsDO.setPricingTierId(pricingTierId);
                incentiveDetailsDO.setMarketingAmount(marketingAmount);
                incentiveDetailsDO.setMarketingIncentive(marketingIncentive);
                incentiveDetailsDO.setAdvertizingIncentive(advertizingIncentive);
                incentiveDetailsDO.setChannelPlacementIncentive(channelPlacementIncentive);
                workFlowDAO.applyIncentives(incentiveDetailsDO);
                closeWindow = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

The

1. pricingTierId ,  marketingIncentive,  advertizingIncentive , 
   channelPlacementIncentive  and channelPlacementIncentive

are passed to the function as null in spite of having getters and setters in the Action class .

I have made the changes as suggested below

```
<s:iterator value="incentiveList" status="stat">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:property value="pricingTierId"  /> <s:hidden name="pricingTierId" value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="marketingAmount" /> <s:hidden name="marketingAmount" value="%{incentiveList.marketingAmount}" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:property value="marketingIncentive" />
                    <s:hidden name="marketingIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:property value="advertizingIncentive"/> 
                    <s:hidden name="advertizingIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}"/> 
                    </td>
                    <td><s:property value="channelPlacementIncentive" /> 
                    <s:hidden name="channelPlacementIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        </s:iterator>
```

Still all the values are being passed as null .
Please suggest

Comment: You are not using **name** attribute in any input field. That's why it giving null . Just give name attribute to input field .

Comment: Aadd the s:hidden for those fields too, as you've already done for other fields.

Comment: Andrea
Please show me example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form will be look like this .

```
<s:form target="_top" cssClass="table-controls form-wrapper" name="incentives" id="frmIncentives" action="saveIncentives.action" method="post">
        <div id="actionErrors" style="color: red;">
                        <s:actionerror />
                        <s:fielderror />
        </div>
            <table id ="showIncentives" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="500" >
                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                    <td><s:checkbox name="Select All" id="select_all"
                            theme="simple" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Marketing Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Advertising Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><s:text name="Channel Placement Incentive" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>
            <s:iterator value="incentiveList" status="stat">
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="pricingTierId" /> <s:hidden name="pricingTierId" value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}" /></td>
                        <td><s:property value="marketingAmount" /> <s:hidden name="marketingAmount" value="%{incentiveList.marketingAmount}" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="marketingIncentive" /><s:hidden name="marketingIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.marketingIncentive}" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="advertizingIncentive" /><s:hidden name="advertizingIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.advertizingIncentive}" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><s:property value="channelPlacementIncentive" /><s:hidden name="channelPlacementIncentive" value="%{incentiveList.channelPlacementIncentive}" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
            </s:iterator>
            </table>
            <c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) == 0}">
                <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="true"/>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) gt 0}">
                <s:submit id="submitButton" name="submit" value="Submit Incentives" onclick='return closeWindow()' disabled="false"/>
            </c:if>
    </s:form>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen but 1 question why  value="%{incentiveList.pricingTierId}"  is repeated in few place in hidden name for other attributes